eth_getBlockByNumber loop in truffle genache
When writing contracts and testing them with truffle develop, I like to have two terminals:
truffle develop --log
truffle develop

One is for logs so I see what is happening and in another one I test. However, whenever I call any transaction (not view), the truffle develop repeats eth_getBlockByNumber call, making logs hard to read. Once I close truffle develop, the calls stop. How can I prevent it?
